# Find basic and non basic variables

Tags: linear-programming

The objective row of a tableau is 2x+u+5v+z=21, where z is the objective function variable.For each x, u, v, decide if it is a basic or non-basic variables in the tableau.Are all non-basic variables(NBV) of the LP the NBV?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do, what output are you expecting, and what are you getting instead? If you haven't done so already, please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Only the objective function is given. the question is asking if the variables(x,u,v) are basic or non-basic. I have no idea how to do this. Like how do we know if the variables are basic or non-basic without knowing the constraints?

Comment: Ah, now I see - this is a linear programming problem, which would be more suitable in Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com), where other statisticians will be able to help you out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Interpret the coefficients of the objective row in a tableau as the **reduced cost** of the corresponding column.

We know the following: if a variable is **basic**, then its corresponding reduced cost is zero. (If a variable is **non-basic** the reduced cost is likely nonzero, but it can be zero.)

This means: if the reduced cost is non-zero, the variable must be non-basic.

So *(x,u,v)* are non-basic.

I don't understand the sentence: *Are all non-basic variables(NBV) of the LP the NBV?* so I cannot help with that.